# jQuery on load function not Working with new version Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I was previously having a jQuery conflict in my WordPress / WooCommerce set-up.

To fix this issue, I reverted back to the jQuery that is included in WordPress

```
// Remove themes old version of jQuery and load a compatible version
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'update_jquery_for_cherry_framework', 11);

function update_jquery_for_cherry_framework() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', false, false, true);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

When I made this change, all my jQuery functions started failing and chrome Console started outputting the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

To fix this issue, I had to encapsulate my functions like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
// script
});
```

This fixed the jQuery conflicts and they all started working again.
My Issue is I'm only able to figure out how to fix this issue with `(document).ready` instances.

One of my jQuery functions must trigger AFTER the document ready function, or in other words the `window.onload` function.

Here is the script in question:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".parallax-slider").css({
    'margin-left': $(".parallax-bg").css("marginLeft")
  });
  $(".parallax-slider").fadeIn(2500 , function(){
    $(this).css("display","normal");
  });
  $(window).resize(function(){
    $(".parallax-slider").css({
    'margin-left': $(".parallax-bg").css("marginLeft")
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Right now, as I stated previously, I'm getting the `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function` error on this for the line `$(window).load(function() {`

I've tried multiple things, such as changing it to `jQuery(window).load(function($){`

like this

```
jQuery(window).load(function($){
$(window).resize(function(){
    $(".parallax-slider").css({
'margin-left': $(".parallax-bg").css("marginLeft")
  });
 });
});
```

but then I still get the error `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function` for `$(window).resize(function(){`

I've also tried other things like adding `})(jQuery);` at the end of my code.

As I've said everything is working fine for `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`'s... how do I get my script to work in the instance when I need to use `$(window).load(function() {` or `jQuery(window).load(function($){` or whatever it may be?

edit:

solution thanks to @abourne

```
<script>
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  jQuery(".parallax-slider").css({
    'margin-left': jQuery(".parallax-bg").css("marginLeft")
  });
  jQuery(".parallax-slider").fadeIn(2500 , function(){
    jQuery(this).css("display","normal");
  });
jQuery(window).resize(function(){
       jQuery(".parallax-slider").css({
    'margin-left': jQuery(".parallax-bg").css("marginLeft")
  });
  });
});
</script>
```

Basically I had to change the instances of `$` to `jQuery`. Reloaded and it is working as it should with no console errors.

Comment: i think you should perform your issue, by giving wordpress version diff, or an url or something a little bit more helpful :) are you sure do not having made duplicate of jquery include ?

Comment: Well my scripts work fine.. I'm just having lots of trouble figuring out how to encapsulate my new jQuery to work with `window.onload`.. all the other jQuery instances work fine for `document.ready`.  I checked my `jquery.js` file I enqueued and it states `jQuery v1.12.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(window).load(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
       $(".parallax-slider").css({
         'margin-left': $(".parallax-bg").css("marginLeft")
       });
    });
  });
```

Is actually very close to what you need. Try replacing

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
```

with

```
 jQuery(window).resize(function(){
```

and same with

```
 $(".parallax-slider").css({
```

to

```
jQuery(".parallax-slider").css({
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited the original question with the entire solution based off your method.  Considering `document.ready` was using `$` fine I was going in all different directions trying to get `on.load` working. Thanks for the solution!